# How do I add a User control to Content Page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have to create a Cross Platform Application using Xamarin Forms. Here I am going to use a third party user control Templates for design. But the usercontrol and content page have a different base classes .

How do i achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAML then you should probably take a look at XAML [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces). Otherwise, simply add your namespace to your code & you should be able to use your controls.

For XAML, [here](https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/SPYROtalks-2-Xamarin/blob/master/SPYROtalks/LottieSample/Views/LottieSamplePage.xaml) you can find a sample of using custom control (line 11). Namespace declaration in line 4.